# How can I automatically mount "instance storage" on an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm facing a problem at the moment in trying to use AWS: "Instance storage" is not always automatically mounted. And depending on the instance type, the device names for the SSD volumes can vary. Sometimes one of the two SSD's is already automatically mounted and sometimes it isn't. (It seems from my experience that the second SSD is never automatically mounted.) Sometimes the instance storage already has a filesystem on it, and sometimes it doesn't.

It would be nice to have a start up script that automatically finds the SSD storage, if there is any, formats it if need be, and then mounts it as a single RAID0 logical volume. But given the variability of situations that the script might face, this doesn't seem like a trivial task. Unless we always use the same instance type, in which case, maybe we can depend on things being a certain way. (But we don't want to have to always use the same instance type.)

It seems crazy to me that Amazon doesn't provide some off-the shelf solution for this problem. I.e., a tool that just mounts all the available instance storage as a single logical volume under `/mnt`, or whatever.

Is there any such off-the-shelf solution for this somewhere, or am I going to have to reinvent the wheel yet again?

It seems like quite a shame that Amazon makes this so difficult. I'm not sure what they are thinking with respect to this!

Answer (score 5):

Presumably the variety of possible real world solutions renders it difficult to come up with something sufficiently generic, though I agree that an opinionated default approach by AWS would go a long away.

Anyway, while it might be a bit more advanced than what you are currently looking for, Leon Mergen's [Automatically mounting instance store on an AWS AMI](http://www.leonmergen.com/sysadmin/2015/08/13/automatically-mounting-instance-store-on-an-aws-ami.html) seems to provide quite some fragments to base your solution on at least, if it doesn't turn out to match your use case just fine.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I want! (Assuming it works properly.) Thanks!